# Smooth scroll glitch in Firefox, fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, smooth-scrolling

Please [see here](http://rentgive.jamesallison.co/) for my example. In Chrome, you click one of the anchor links and it smoothly scrolls down to 100px above the section with the corresponding  `div` `id`. For some reason in Firefox, it does this smooth scroll nicely but then glitches back so the page is scrolled cutting into the `<h2>` of this section, not 100px above. Sorry if this is poorly explained, hopefully you can see what I mean with the example.

Here is the jquery used for the smooth scroll:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var target = this.hash;
            var $target = $(target);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -100
            }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.slider').unslider({
            dots: true,
            fluid: true,
            delay: 10000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Generally we like to see source code for debugging your issues. However, I know the problem so I will provide a solution for you.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Code added, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within the script at the bottom of the page:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var target = this.hash;
                var $target = $(target);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -100
                }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target; // Right here
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Modify the `hash` to also reflect `-100`:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var target = this.hash;
                var $target = $(target);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top -100
                }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target -100; // Like so
                });
            });
        });
```

Feel free to look here for evidence:

http://jsfiddle.net/zkyz6m5m/

By telling the window location via the hash, it is jumping to the actual anchor point instead of -100 during the functions callback in the initial example.

Comment: If this accurately answered your problem, please select the green checkbox next to the answer.

Comment: This is now adding a #NaN to the URI, rather than the actual anchor?